# After partitioning space to my ubuntu partition, nothing updates

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, upgrade, update-manager, sudo

Right now, I have Ubuntu 13.04, and using `sudo-apt-get dist-upgrade` does not get me the 13.10 update.

Whenever I `sudo-apt-update` or `upgrade` lately, I get:

`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`.

It has been for a couple of months (I'm not actually sure, but it has been a long time), and I want to fix this somehow.

Edit: from `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Edit 2: from `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` to comment out the last two lines

Edit 3: I found out the problem on my own.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main multiverse restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main multiverse restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main universe multiverse restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main multiverse restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
## deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all
## deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/person/ppa/ubuntu karmic main
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: It says, "Permission Denied" even though I am the administrator.

Comment: If it says permission denied you are _not_ the administrator. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: I have posted what I have seen. Also, why am I not the administrator? I installed the partition, and I am the sole user.

Comment: Because that's not how Linux works, you have set up a normal user, who has the right to _become_ the administrator by using `sudo`. It's a very different paradigm than Windows.

Comment: Oh okay. But then, I am still clueless as to how I will fix this problem.

Comment: The last 2 lines should be removed or commented out.

Comment: And so am I which is why I only posted a comment about the "being administrator" part :) The "admin" username on Linux is `root` by the way.

Comment: Danatela, why would the last two lines be adjusted as such?

Comment: Danatela, I commented the last two lines, but I still have a problem of the update being unable to calculate (as explained below Benoit's answer. Terdon, you have anymore suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. I ran the command of `sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-*` which means that there are other third-party software I did not remove for the upgrade of 13.04 to 13.10.

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181779

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what it seems, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does not upgrade to the new version if you do not changes the sources before.

The correct command is `sudo update-manager` or `sudo update-manager -d`.

More info in http://www.unixmen.com/upgrade-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander/

Comment: I face two problems. 1. It tells me I am upgrading to a beta release even though I am certain that 13.10 is finally stable. 2. It then tells me to stop installation, for the manager cannot calculate the software upgrade.

Comment: Try without the `-d`...

Comment: That solved one of my problems. Yet, the manager still tells me that it still "cannot calculate the upgrade".

Answer (score 2):

apt-get dist-upgrade does not perform a distribution upgrade to the next release as it sounds. 
From the man page :

> dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,also intelligently handles changing
>   dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution >system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less >important ones if necessary.

If you want to upgrade to the next available release of Ubuntu, you can do this by using the `do-release-upgrade` at the command line.
This command will automatically generate the required `/etc/apt/sources.list` file for the next release.

Comment: For some reason, /etc/apt/sources.list is saying, "Permission Denied."

Comment: And, for do-release-upgrade, it says, "Could not calculate the upgrade".

Comment: "Could not calculate the upgrade" may be a result of using external sources of packages you may have added. In your `sources.list` attached with your original question, I see that the two last lines are external sources, comment these two lines and see if the command can run.

Comment: Don't forget to use `sudo` when you are manipulating the `sources.list` file, this should remove the "Permission Denied" errors.

Comment: I commented the last two lines out, but it still "Could not calculate the upgrade".

Answer (score 0):

Open the software and updates application and tab to updates. Ensure you have option 'Notify me of a new ubuntu version' set to 'For any new version'. It may be that you have updates set to only download LTS versions, which is the default option.

Comment: The LTS has never been on default for me. I think LTS updates are default if I download a LTS version.